# Attempting to $push into a collection does not push multiple items

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, nosql

I am new to `NoSQL` and `MongoDB` and I am trying to `$push` an `array` into another field that is an `array`.

I am trying to `push` `$dynamicInfo` into my user's `profile.weightTracker` so that I can have a `new array` into `weightTracker` the current code push by replace but not `push` the `array` as a `new array` every time I refresh the page / run the scrip but instead re-writes the current.

Could anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
$dynamicInfo['currentWeight'] = '83';

$user = $this->db()->users;

// Deals with the static info that just need an update
if ( empty( $staticInfo ) == false ) {
    $user->update(
        array('_id' => new MongoId( $userId ) ),
        array('$set' => array('profile' => $staticInfo) ),
        array('upsert' => True)
    );
}

// Deals with the dynamic info that needs to be inserted as array
if ( empty( $dynamicInfo ) == false ) {
    //$dynamicInfo['inserted_on'] = new MongoDate();
    $user->update(
        array('_id' => new MongoId( $userId ) ),
        array('$push' => array('profile.weightTracker' => $dynamicInfo ) ),
        array('safe' => True)
    );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to expect that the code that deals with static information over writes the document each time you run it, and then the code that deals with dynamic information just the first array element again. In other words, I don't think `$staticInfo` is empty when you expect it to be.

If you do:

```
$user->update(
    array( '_id' => 42 ),
    array( '$set' => array( 'profile.weightTracker' => array( 'height' => 82 ) ) )
);
```

and then:

```
$user->update(
    array( '_id' => 42 ),
    array( '$set' => array( 'profile' => array( 'height' => 176 ) ) )
);
```

Then the *whole* array `profile` will be set to `array( 'height' => 176 )`. It doesn't matter if you have set `'profile.weightTracker'` to some other value before.

You can't set an array (`profile`) and expect sub keys that you don't specify in the first update (`profiler.weightTracker`) to survive.

However, what you can do is this — simply build up the `$set` array and run the update in one go:

```
$user->update(
    array( '_id' => 42 ),
    array(
        '$push' => array( 'profile.weightTracker' => array( 'currentWeight' => 82 ) ),
        '$set' => array( 'profile.height' => 176 )
    )
);
```

Comment: I want one update to be executed first and then the other one depending on whether the independent variables are set.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. But I can not guess what the contents of your variables are!

Comment: `$dynamicInfo` is an `array` as I've briefly shown its content in the top of the code. thats the array using the $push

Comment: I fixed it now. Given that I can not have 2 update statements doing 2 different things within the same function aparently. is there anyway to have 2 different update statements in the same function so that I do not have that problem??? (basically is there a way to make what i intended to do work?)

Comment: You can have 2 different update statements doing whatever you want. But you can't set an array (``profile``) and expect sub keys that you don't specify to survive. Updated the answer.

Comment: But `height` is a `$set` whereas `weightTracker` contains multiple arrays thats why i need the `$push`. when i try that code that you amended it all works as a set and not as as `$set` and `$push`. as i need them both, given that the content is different